# finding sum of numbers in a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, sum, numbers

I'm trying to find the sum of the numbers in a char array.

My code works for most cases. Example : `a=dasn344wee22ee`, the output is:`366` - which is good

But when my char is,for example : `andre54e5` the output should be `59`, but the program displays: `108`.

Can anybody tell me what the issue is?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int getnr(char a[], int i, int j)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char sir[1000];
    for (int x = i; x<j; x++)
    {
        sir[counter] = a[x];
        counter++;
    }
    return atoi(sir);

}
int main()
{
    char a[1000];
    int s = 0, inceput, finals;
    cin.getline(a, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(a[i]) )
        {
            if (i == strlen(a) - 1)
            {
                s += getnr(a, i, strlen(a));
            }

            for (int j = i + 1; j<strlen(a); j++)
            {
                if (!isdigit(a[j])  || j == strlen(a) - 1)
                {
                    s += getnr(a, i, j + 1);
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get 59 with the input `andre54e5`. I can't reproduce your problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: It’s C++. Use std::string and not char arrays and str* functions.

Comment: [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)?

Comment: @manni66: But `strtol` and `strtod` have better error handling than either `atoi` (which just punts on most errors without graceful recovery) or `std::string`-based `sto` *`x`* family of functions (which have graceful recovery but don't provide machine-accessible information on what the problem was)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `int getnr(char a[], int i, int j)`, you forgot to null-terminate string `sir`, such that `atoi(sir)` might yield a garbage value (actually the behaviour is undefined). The following should help:

```
int getnr(char a[], int i, int j)` {
    ...
    sir[counter] = '\0';
    return atoi(sir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getnr()` doesn't add a null terminator to the `sir` array, so you're getting undefined behavior when you call `atoi(sir)`.

```
int getnr(char a[], int i, int j)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char sir[1000];
    for (int x = i; x<j; x++)
    {
        sir[counter] = a[x];
        counter++;
    }
    sir[counter] = '\0';
    return atoi(sir);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is within this part of code:

```
if (i == strlen(a) - 1)
{
   s += getnr(a, i, strlen(a));
}
```

Specifically, if your last number is a single digit (which it is), it will always return junk.

So, I would change to only convert the single char of the char array as a digit and at it to the int s.

*Edit*:
For some reason when doing `s+= a[i]`, I return junk.
But, doing the following, does the trick:

```
if (i == strlen(a) - 1)
{
    string x;
    x[0] = a[i];
    int l = stoi(x);
    s += l;
}
```

I know that there's a much more effective way, but I'm not sure why `s+= a[i]` itself returns false numbers.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but my task, this time, is not to determine the sum of all digits in a char array. ex: and23ds3, as you suggest, it would be:8; Instead,   my task would expect an answer like this : 26.

Comment: Actually, the for loop within if a[i] is a digit would still return the full digit "23" (from your example in the comment). However, in a different example, if you were attempting to parse "abcd23abc24," you would never go into the nested if loop after the first '23' is found (which I point out to be the issue), because a[i] would be positioned for 2, which would not return true for if (i == strlen(a) - 1), consequently, leading for the continuation of the char array to be parsed, returning for s+= '24'